# How to convert a column containing timestamps into epoch time in a csv file

Tags: bash, csv, date, epoch

I am trying to convert a column (25th) of a csv file containing timestamps into epoch time using bash.

The format of timestamps is **YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss**  (i.e. : 2020/02/10 10:27:21)

> original_column=$(awk -F';' '{print $26}' file.csv)

I wrote the following to convert the values :

> converted_column=$(date -d $(echo $original_column) +%s)

**Output :**

> echo $converted_column

**Error :**

> date: extra operand `2020-02-10'

**Expected output**

> 1581330441

Would anyone know what is the proper syntax ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

You don't need an echo to feed the date to `date`:

```
converted_column=$(date -d "$original_column" +%s)
```

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. The output is better as timestamps are now displayed, but not converted into epoch time. I am going to try one of the suggested solutions in "Converting timestamp to EPOCH in awk".